# Failed to fetch 'InRelease' in Debian9's apt

Tags: debian, apt, source

I want to update the source of apt, so I execute:

```
apt update
```

Then, error message is printed:

```
Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
```

However, I explore the sources by another device and noticed that, the 'InRelease' file cannot be found in any mirror source, whereas 'Release' file is always there.

That's confusing and and I find no solution in Google. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it really "Clearsigned fule isn't valid, git 'NOSPLIT'"? Doing a search gives me "Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT'", which seems rather more likely. Editing.

Comment: Do you happen to be using a proxy? Doing a quick search suggest that proxy misconfigurations can be to blame.

Comment: Crossposted on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/q/46502543/350713. Please don't crosspost.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update -o Debug::Acquire::http=1` and paste the output into your question, please.